# jQuery draggable "game" questions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So I have a "game" like feature, more of a quiz but I cannot get my head around how to get it working.
HTML

```
<td id='1to7 value' class="boxes" value="1to7"> Text here </td>
```

So this is the jQuery

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $(".boxes").draggable();
      $("#one,#droppable").droppable({
          drop: function (event, ui) {
              $( this )
              alert("testing!");
            }
      });
  });
</script>
```

As you can see it's going to alert on everything that is being dropped on `#one` or `#droppable`.

Now here is the catch. I have different boxes with different values (1 to 7).

Each `.draggable` area has a ID (1 to 7, and 7 `.draggable` areas in total).

How can I check that the correct box has been dragged onto the correct `.draggable` area and then check that after all boxes have been dragged (with a submit).

Comment: What is your validation criteria? How draggable element you'l consider as a valid drop? pl. explain

Comment: So I would like to do something like `if($(this).val() == 1){alert("Dropped!")}`,  `$(this)` being what has just been dropped. So get the Value from that element and check that it == 1

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then draggable element should go to its original position if its != 1 right??

Comment: Yes it should revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get draggable object from `ui.drabbable` and check its `val()` for testing.

```
$(function () {
  $(".boxes").draggable(
      {revert: 'invalid',
       stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
      }
     }
  );

  $("#droppable").droppable({
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        if(draggable.attr("value")==1)
            alert("correct!");
          else
            draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
       }
  });
```

});

you can't make `<td>` draggable, instead you have to use something like `<span>` or `<div>`

```
<span class="boxes" value="1"> Draggable1 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="2"> Draggable2 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="3"> Draggable3 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="4"> Draggable4 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="5"> Draggable5 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="6"> Draggable6 </span>
<span class="boxes" value="7"> Draggable7 </span>
<div id="droppable">
    droppable area
</div>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgpu6/2/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, if I do a `.val()` on the draggable element I get "" ...

Comment: @TidusJar, revert back `if invalid draggable` is added. check answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `accept:` specifier: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/droppable.php

You can use the onDrop event to set flags to determine whether all of the desired objects have been dropped at the end.